# Configuring and adding clients to use wordpress as an OpenId provider

Tags: php, wordpress, openid, openid-connect

I'm currently new in the world of php and wordpress. I want to setup my wordpress as an openId provider, currently I have installed this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/openid/ to enable my wordpress as an openid provider, the issue I'm facing is where do I set up a client that will use my wordpress as openId provider. When I visit settings then openId I see no options to create a client. Below I have attached a screenshot displaying what I see once I select openId. Any help will be much appreciated thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the plugin what you're using is outdated and not recommended to use for security purposes. Better give a try [OpenID](https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-openid-connect-client/)

Comment: Hmm... that doesn't seem to be able to convert wordpress into an openid provider but rather just as a client to work with other openid providers.

Comment: Hope, you're looking for something similar [WordPress Auth Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-oauth-20-server/). Since the plugin does support to add one client in free version.